# Python sorting a nested list with conditional comparison

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, key

I am trying to sort a nested list `A`. `len(A) = n` and `len(A[i]) = d` for all `i`. I would like to sort using the first element of `A[i]`. But if `A[i][0] == A[j][0]` then I want to sort using the next element, i.e., `A[i][1]`. If `A[i][1] == A[j][1]` then use the next element, `A[i][2]`, and so on.

Here is an example with `n = 4` and `d = 2`. Because `[3,6]` and `[3,7]` have the same first element, they are compared based on the second element.

```
A = [[3,7], [4,5], [3, 6], [5,1]]
A_sorted = [[3,6], [3,7], [4,5], [5,1]]
```

In Python 2.7 I used custom comparison function. 
`A.sort(cmp=comp_func)`. But I am trying to do this in Python 3 which does not have the `cmp` argument option. So I need to use `key` argument instead. How do I implement this custom sorting in Python 3?

Comment: `A_sorted = sorted(A)` gives the desired result in both python2 and python3. No need for a `key` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default Python sorting behavior.  Have you tried doing this and it hasn't worked?